# Problem while printing classes of ontology in python3

Tags: python, ontology, protege, protege4, owlready

[image]I'm using owlready2. I loaded a local .owl file( [.owl file I'm using](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApI8EVfC6WmRiGHzP8HIeg9lEfAN?e=Geozfz)) , it has a class Radiometry. I did the following:

```
 from owlready2 import *
 onto=get_ontology("file:///Users/adarshkumar/Downloads/ontology.owl").load()
 print(onto.Radiometry)
```

The output was None

Why am I getting None when I print an already present class in the ontology?

To debug I tried:

```
>>> list(onto.classes())
```

Then I got:

> [owl.Thing, untitled-ontology-17.Radiometry, untitled-ontology-17.Astrophysics,........]

What does untitled-ontology mean, is this the problem?

Full description below:
[image]

I'm new to this and would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide a full reproducible example of the problem you are having please?

Comment: @NickMartin, Why am I getting None when I print a class already present in the ontology?

Comment: Like I said, can you provide a fully working piece of code that can in isolation be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @NickMartin I've updated the code

Comment: That's all I'm doing

Comment: It's not reproducible if you don't provide your input file...

Comment: @NickMartin I've added the link for the file I'm using